# Best book for design inspiration

Tags: book

I recently thought of buying some good graphic design inspiration book. but the problem is choice, I got a big list of book and I don't know which one to buy. I prefer books with a lot of pictures.My main subject is posters and creative drawings. no UI Design. (eg: behance creative book, iron fist etc). Can anyone suggestion good book and why you are suggesting me. I believe a lot in community, so I like to hear from you guys. This is my first question too :). Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi Jaison, as it stands this question is incredibly broad. A book - with pictures - that inspires. There's only a couple hundred thousand of those. If you can try to edit the question to be something more specific it might work, MIGHT. I'm really not sure there is a way to make this question not entirely opinion based.

Comment: Sorry but its still too broad. I mean what inspires me, and what inspires you, and what inspires someone else could be completely different things. Maybe you find inspiration in an illustrated bible, I might find inspiration in punk rock posters from the 1980s, another person in back issues of high fashion magazines, and someone else in art nouveau books.. The point is this question can't be answered as it stands. What inspires you is not going to be the same as anyone else.

Comment: There is no 'best' book in any category.

Answer (score 2):

A book on inspiration would in time become outdated, expensive and some books are based on the current trends.  If you're looking for inspiration instead of purchasing a book I would look for websites pertaining to the field you have in mind.

(**An example for web**)  I frequently like to visit sites such as:

- [CSS Design Awards](http://www.cssdesignawards.com/)
- [Awwwards](http://www.awwwards.com/)
- [Bootstrap Expo](http://expo.getbootstrap.com/)
- [Foundation Examples](http://foundation.zurb.com/learn/website-examples.html)

For my book collection on my shelf I go with:

- The Web Designer's Idea Book

Mind you the book is on it's 4th volume so if you're looking to go this route I would look at current sites and only get books if you like collecting books around your field because at 20+ a pop you will almost spend 100 dollars on a printed version.

Comment: sorry i forget to mention what subject i am looking for. I edited the question with the subject that i am interested. its poster design, creative drawn. no UI design. But Thank you for the time you spend for the answer.

Comment: It still applies to any subject, I just used web as an example.

Comment: Yup, but the most are Website and Mobile app design, that's why... but while searching i found some books which is very similar that i am looking for, this is the one http://www.amazon.in/dp/1594745439/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pC_nS_ttl?_encoding=UTF8&colid=2V6F63G0GZBS4&coliid=I353W1KX9OULK2

Answer (score 1):

"Best" is subjective. I don't think there is an ultimate inspirational book. Inspiration comes from anywhere/everywhere depending on your state of mind at a given time.
Why not accumulate a collection of books over time?

Comment: you are right, inspiration comes from everywhere. but why I thought of buying books because to get out of computer (professionally I am a coder). Subject's I love mostly poster and book design, then scenes can be anything like steampunk, space, historical etc..